# How to show fields of inherited model in django?

Tags: django

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):  # base class should subclass 'django.db.models.Model'

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(..) # define the common field1

    class Meta:
        abstract=True # Set this model as Abstract
```

Inherit this Base class in models

After creating the abstract base class BaseModel, I inherited this class in my models.

```
class MyModel1(BaseModel): # inherit the base model class

    # define other non-common fields here
    ...
```

After creating an object of class 'MyModel1', I want the 'creation_date' field to be shown in admin interface.
So that I can see the datetime when an object of class 'MyModel1' is created.

Comment: provide your admin.py file

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I got your point. Its working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class MyModel1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields= ['creation_date',]

admin.site.register(MyModel1,MyModel1Admin)
```